# Connecting to YouTube API and download URLs - getting KeyError

Tags: python

My goal is to connect to Youtube API and download the URLs of specific music producers.I found the following script which I used from the following link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_M_wle0Iq9M. In the video the code works beautifully. But when I try it on python 2.7 it gives me KeyError:'items'.

I know KeyErrors can occur when there is an incorrect use of a dictionary or when a key doesn't exist.

I have tried going to the google developers site for youtube to make sure that 'items' exist and it does.

I am also aware that using get() may be helpful for my problem but I am not sure. Any suggestions to fixing my KeyError using the following code or any suggestions on how to improve my code to reach my main goal of downloading the URLs (I have a Youtube API)?

Here is the code:

```
#these modules help with HTTP request from Youtube
import urllib 
import urllib2 
import json 


API_KEY = open("/Users/ereyes/Desktop/APIKey.rtf","r") 
API_KEY = API_KEY.read() 

searchTerm = raw_input('Search for a video:')

searchTerm = urllib.quote_plus(searchTerm) 

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q='+searchTerm+'&key='+API_KEY  

response = urllib.urlopen(url) 

videos = json.load(response) 

videoMetadata = [] #declaring our list

for video in videos['items']: #"for loop" cycle through json response and searches in items 

    if video['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video': #makes sure that item we are looking at is only videos
        videoMetadata.append(video['snippet']['title']+ # getting title of video and putting into list
        "\nhttp://youtube.com/watch?v="+video['id']['videoId'])                       

videoMetadata.sort(); # sorts our list alphaetically

print ("\nSearch Results:\n")  #print out search results

for metadata in videoMetadata:
    print (metadata)+"\n"

raw_input('Press Enter to Exit')
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `videos` to see what is in there?  e.g. `print json.dumps(videos, indent=2)`.  Perhaps the API is giving you some sort of error response (Unauthorized or something)

Comment: Side question: Why are you storing an API key in an RTF file?

Comment: @cricket_007 That might not actually be a side question. The RTF format tends to include some junk for formatting at the head of the file. Perhaps that junk is being sent as part of the API key to YouTube, which would cause a 401 (or some other error of that ilk).

Comment: @pzp Good point... I didn't even think about that

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your comments. I just followed the YouTube tutorial (see above for link). However, the author of the tutorial did not use a RTF; He used TXT file. He did this to hide his API key.  To be honest it worked for them so I figure it would work for me. I will try to use a TXT file instead unless you have another suggestion.

Comment: Hiding the key is a good idea. I might consider using json file though, if you did need to store other configuration settings

Comment: @mgilson Thank you for your suggestion.  (I have only been "coding" for 2-3 weeks so please my simple question). Where in my script do you suggest I insert this line of code? I have tried putting it in the line before "for video in video['items']" and in the line right after but they don't seem to work.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, I will try to store my key in a json file instead and see if that works.

Comment: To answer your question, You would print out the response of the url download immediately after it finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely a combination of using an RTF file instead of a plain text file for the API key and you seem to be confused whether to use urllib or urllib2 since you imported both.

Personally, I would recommend [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), but I think you need to **read()** the contents of the request to get a string

```
response = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

You can check that by printing the response variable

Comment: It worked! The RTF file was the issue but once I switched over to TXT file it worked well. (so simple yet so difficult when one is new to the coding world). Many thanks!